# Is it possible to use boost::program_options to capture arguments w/o dash?

Tags: c++, boost

With **boost::program_options**, if the arguments are not part of `-`, `--` or `/` options(neither the options themselves nor their possible values), can I capture the list of these arguments separately?

For example, I'd like to write a `ls` program. I hope I can have similar implementation like:

```
ls -l --color=always <file_dir_1> <file_dir_2> ... <file_dir_n>
```

where I can capture `<file_dir_1>` ... `<file_dir_n>` and handle them specially.

Comment: It's addressed in the [tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/program_options/tutorial.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are termed "positional options". Boost.Program Options handles these by forwarding to an existing option by name:

```
po::positional_options_description p;
p.add("input-file", -1); // forward positional options to "input-file" option

po::variables_map vm;
po::store(po::command_line_parser(ac, av). // replace po::parse_command_line(...)
          options(desc).positional(p).run(), vm);
po::notify(vm);
```

You would want to have "input-file" as an existing option of type `std::vector<std::string>`.